# Is there a simple way to explain quantised conductance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrical-resistance, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, discrete

I am biologist and I need to pass a nanotechnology class. I am stuck with this term of [quantum resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_quantum). Basically this appears to me as normal Ohm's law, except that takes into account Heisenberg uncertainty principle. Is this an OK way of thinking, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Superconductors have zero resistance despite being perfectly quantum mechanical systems. What you are probably thinking about is the quantum hall effect... what that has to do with biology only the heavens of poorly picked courses know.

Comment: nanotechnology have a lot to do with biology @CuriousOne !

Comment: My guess would be that this refers to the quantum Hall effect. I've never come across the idea of quantum resistance in any other context.

Comment: I guess you are right, there is uncertainty here, on quite a few levels.

Comment: @CuriousOne It takes little effort to imagine a case wherein I'd like to measure something on the cellular or even molecular (ever heard of DNA?) level in a biological system. I would think any available signals are rather weak and that sensors operating in the so-called "nano" world could be relevant.

Comment: @DanielSank: Some of my commercial clients are supplying nano-technology based biological reagents and diagnostics, so I actually know the field a little bit. The science, design and manufacturing of these products falls squarely into physics, chemistry and engineering and the OP is very poorly prepared for either field.

Comment: @CuriousOne Are there really no applications of Hall sensors in biology?

Comment: @DanielSank: I have an application for  civil engineering in physics: there is usually a paved road and a bridge or two between where I live and where I go to work in a physics lab. Does that count? In any case... the OP is confused about the most basic concepts here. I don't think he actually listened to what they have been trying to teach. That's just my impression, of course. I did, of course, mention quantum hall effect myself.

Comment: @CuriousOne Pretty sure this question is about contact resistance in ballistic conductors (see answer below), since this is actually relevant for nanotechnology. Not sure where the hall effect ideas have come from here.

Comment: why are you now relating quantum resistance and hall effect?

Comment: chapters that will be on following midterm, 1) STM, AFM 2) Fractal dimension, skewness 3) nanofabrications 4) CVD, carbonnanotubes 5) Quantum resistance 6) Understanding of concepts Is this usual curriculum?

Comment: Funny thing - and ridiculous too - closing a question after the accepted answer makes it clear that it does make perfect sense if concepts are properly recognized. At least you could engage the author of said answer for clarifications? To those who are not afraid to postpone jumping to conclusions so eagerly, please check Supriyo Datta's book "Quantum Transport: Atom to Transistor", his courses on http://nanohub.org, and even an old (!!) bio ref: http://www.mcc.uiuc.edu/summerschool/2002/Trudy%20vanderStraaten/vanderStraaten_files/talk.pdf. And brush up on nanophysics, for Pete's sakes.

Comment: Voting to reopen because there's a valid question in there, but this is a very muddled post for sure.

Comment: Agreed that the question was far from clear, but nevertheless a minute's effort makes it quite clear what's going on here. I have edited the question and added a Wikipedia link so that the confused close-voters can do some reading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. Ohm's law concerns electric conduction in the scattering regime, when resistivity develops due to the scattering of electrons on the material's ions/atoms , impurities, defects, etc. In this case the mean free path of an electron in the (semi)conductor is much shorter than the dimensions/length of the conductor itself.

Quantum conductance characterizes the ballistic regime, when the size of the nanoscale conductor (molecule, nanotube, quantum dot, etc) is much smaller than the electron mean free path. In this case electrons pass through the nanoconductor essentially without any interaction, and resistivity arises from scattering on end (metal) contacts that act largely like walls to a box. The electrons become quantum particles in a box under applied voltage, while conductance becomes independent of the size of the conductor and quantized, with a conductance quantum of $2e^2/h$.

Since you mention the uncertainty principle, you may want to check the simple derivation in this [Wikipedia paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_quantum#Motivation_from_the_uncertainty_principle). Also useful:

• Wikipedia page on [Ballistic Conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_conduction)

• Beginner friendly [Tutorial on (nano)Electronic Transport](http://nanotube.msu.edu/nt05/abstracts/NT05tutor-Nygard.pdf)

**Note added after comment**

Here is another take at the argument for the conductance quantum:

Current in a nanoconductor may be viewed as carried through a limited number of discrete energy levels or channels. Consider a single one of these channels. In the absence of coupling to contacts, it corresponds to a single state at energy E. But with contacts and a voltage $V$ applied across the contacts, it undergoes a broadening to a continuous band of width $\Delta E \sim eV$. If an electron takes an average time $\tau$ to traverse the conductor through this broadened level, we can say that it produces a current $I = \text{charge through conductor per unit of time}\sim \frac{e}{\tau}$.  The conductance enabling this current is then $G_0 = \frac{I}{V} \sim \frac{e}{\tau} \frac{e}{\Delta E} = \frac{e^2}{\Delta E\; \tau}$. But the average transit time $\tau$ is on the order of the level's lifetime, that is, the average time it takes an electron to transition to another level. On the other hand, the time-energy uncertainty principle relates energy broadening and lifetime as $\Delta E \;\tau \approx \frac{\hbar}{2}$. Substituting this in the expression for the conductance leaves $G_0 = \frac{2 e^2}{\hbar}$.

Comment: thank you, but still I have hard time now to put uncertainty principle ! is there any simpler way?

Comment: @SSimon I added a note on the issue. Does it help?